# How can I run zeppelin with keberos in CDH 6.3.2

Tags: kerberos, apache-zeppelin, livy

zeppelin 0.9.0 does not work with Kerberos

I have add "**zeppelin.server.kerberos.keytab**" and "**zeppelin.server.kerberos.principal**" in zeppelin-site.xml

But I aldo get error "**Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is: "bigdser5/10.3.87.27"; destination host is: "bigdser1":8020;**"

And add "**spark.yarn.keytab**","**spark.yarn.principal**" in spark interpreters,it does not work yet.

In my spark-shell that can work with Kerberos

My kerberos step

1.admin.local -q "addprinc jzyc/hadoop"

2. kadmin.local -q "xst -k jzyc.keytab jzyc/hadoop@JJKK.COM"
3. copy jzyc.keytab to other server
4. kinit -kt jzyc.keytab jzyc/hadoop@JJKK.COM

In my livy I get error "**javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store**"

Comment: Your best option: install an Hortonworks kerberized cluster, read the docs, observe closely what are the settings that Ambari adds/modifies when you add Livy then Zeppelin. Including `core-site.xml` for impersonation.

Comment: in my log , I see "Successfully logged into KDC.",   "getting token for: DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1621061227_37, ugi=jzyc/bigdser4@JOIN.COM (auth:KERBEROS)]] with renewer yarn/bigdser1@JOIN.COM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in spark.jars

you need hdfs://bigdser1:8020/sparklib/tispark-assembly-2.3.14.jar

not

hdfs://bigdser1:8020/sparklib/*

Answer (score 0):

```
INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:46,522] ({dispatcher-event-loop-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - Got an error when resolving hostNames. Falling back to /default-rack for all
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:46,561] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - Attempting to login to KDC using principal: jzyc/bigdser4@JOIN.COM
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:46,574] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - Successfully logged into KDC.
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,124] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - getting token for: DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1346508100_40, ugi=jzyc/bigdser4@JOIN.COM (auth:KERBEROS)]] with renewer yarn/bigdser1@JOIN.COM
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,265] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} DFSClient.java[getDelegationToken]:700) - Created token for jzyc: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=jzyc/bigdser4@JOIN.COM, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1618476287222, maxDate=1619081087222, sequenceNumber=171, masterKeyId=21 on ha-hdfs:nameservice1
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,273] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - getting token for: DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1346508100_40, ugi=jzyc/bigdser4@JOIN.COM (auth:KERBEROS)]] with renewer jzyc/bigdser4@JOIN.COM
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,278] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} DFSClient.java[getDelegationToken]:700) - Created token for jzyc: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=jzyc/bigdser4@JOIN.COM, renewer=jzyc, realUser=, issueDate=1618476287276, maxDate=1619081087276, sequenceNumber=172, masterKeyId=21 on ha-hdfs:nameservice1
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,331] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - Renewal interval is 86400051 for token HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,492] ({dispatcher-event-loop-0} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - Got an error when resolving hostNames. Falling back to /default-rack for all
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,493] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - Scheduling renewal in 18.0 h.
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,494] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - Updating delegation tokens.
 INFO [2021-04-15 16:44:47,521] ({FIFOScheduler-interpreter_1099886208-Worker-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:57) - Updating delegation tokens for current user.
```

Answer (score 0):

INFO [2021-04-23 11:49:29,658] ({qtp1640639994-103} ManagedInterpreterGroup.java[getOrCreateSession]:180) - Create Session: shared_session in InterpreterGroup: md-shared_process for user: anonymous
INFO [2021-04-23 11:49:29,659] ({qtp1640639994-103} InterpreterSetting.java[getOrCreateInterpreterGroup]:453) - Create InterpreterGroup with groupId: spark-shared_process for ExecutionContext{user='anonymous', noteId='2EYUV26VR', interpreterGroupId='null', defaultInterpreterGroup='spark', inIsolatedMode=false, startTime=}
INFO [2021-04-23 11:49:29,659] ({qtp1640639994-103} InterpreterSetting.java[createInterpreters]:823) - Interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter created for user: anonymous, sessionId: shared_session

but I enable shiro.ini